# After a car becomes "sold out" in the used car dealership, how long before it comes back?

Tags: gran-turismo-7

I was waiting for a particular car to become available in the used car dealership, because it cannot be bought or won any other way. Then I went on holidays and the next time I played it was already sold out! I know the dealership refreshes every 24hrs, but how long is it before a sold out car returns? Is there any way to influence it? I managed to add it to my wish list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to attempt an answer based on what I have observed.

When I first started playing the game there was an Impreza for sale and shortly after this a 458 Italia and then an MR2, I remember this because they were the first few cars that I actually bought. It has been about 4 weeks and these 3 cars have now reappeared for sale, not in the same exact order but close. Based on this there seems to be about a 4 week refresh rate.

Happy to get others thoughts on their experience, whether similar or different.